# Azure Site Recovery + MySQL Server on Windows

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault, azure-site-recovery

I'd like to use Azure Site Recovery to backup our Azure VMs that are running MySQL Server. The problem is that I can't find if Azure Site Recovery will properly backup MySQL databases on Windows, nor can I find any mention if MySQL Server does or does not support Volume Shadow Copy (if we need to stop MySQL process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support Volume Shadow Copy as indicated here:
https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?28,689212,689214#msg-689214

Hence, Azure Site Recovery can't backup MySQL databases natively.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Azure site recovery (ASR) to replicate VMs from on-premise VMware, Hyper-V and Physical servers to Azure. You can also set up replication for Azure VMs - Azure to Azure replication. ASR is basically used as BCDR solution.

Reference: [ASR overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-overview) - Check "How-To-Guides" for more information.

If you are planning to use Azure Backup, for your use case I would suggest using Azure backup for SQL Server on Azure VM. References: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-backup-for-sql-server-in-azure-virtual-machines-now-generally-available/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-sql-server-database-azure-vms